# BigDecimal floor rounding goes wrong

Tags: java, bigdecimal, rounding

I recently ask a question about weird java double floor rounding, and got answers to use BigDecimals instead, so tried the following code:

```
BigDecimal velocity = new BigDecimal(-0.07);
BigDecimal afterMultiplyingBy200 = velocity.multiply( new BigDecimal(200.0) );
BigDecimal floored = afterMultiplyingBy200.setScale(0, RoundingMode.FLOOR);
System.out.println("After multiplication " + afterMultiplyingBy200);
System.out.println("floored value is " + floored);
```

And I'm getting following results

```
After multiplication -14.000000000000001332267629550187848508358001708984375000
floored value is -15
```

It seems that even using BigDecimal I can't get correct value for multiplying -0.07 by 200, is there anything that I can do to get exactly -14.0?

Comment: If you change the question from a rounding question to a multiplication question, why preserve the wrong title?

Answer (score 7):

From my answer to that question:

> When the code is compiled or interpreted, your “0.1” is already
>   rounded to the nearest number in that format, which results in a small
>   rounding error even before the calculation happens.

The problem is that `new BigDecimal(-0.07);` uses a `double` literal to initialize the `BigDecimal` - so the error still happens. Use the `BigDecimal` constructor that takes a `String` instead.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the [string constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28java.lang.String%29) to avoid rounding errors due to the use of doubles:

```
BigDecimal velocity = new BigDecimal("-0.07");
BigDecimal afterMultiplyingBy200 = velocity.multiply(new BigDecimal("200"));
```

Javadoc extract for the [constructor using doubles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#BigDecimal%28double%29) - emphasis mine:

> 1. The results of this constructor can be somewhat unpredictable. One might assume that writing new BigDecimal(0.1) in Java creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1 (an unscaled value of 1, with a scale of 1), but it is actually equal to 0.1000000000000000055511151231257827021181583404541015625. This is because 0.1 cannot be represented exactly as a double (or, for that matter, as a binary fraction of any finite length). Thus, the value that is being passed in to the constructor is not exactly equal to 0.1, appearances notwithstanding.
> 2. The String constructor, on the other hand, is perfectly predictable: writing new BigDecimal("0.1") creates a BigDecimal which is exactly equal to 0.1, as one would expect. Therefore, **it is generally recommended that the String constructor be used** in preference to this one.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is right here:

```
BigDecimal velocity = new BigDecimal(-0.07);
```

`-0.07` cannot be represented exactly as a `double`, so the literal value passed to the `BigDecimal` constructor ends up being slightly different than `-0.07`. `BigDecimal` just takes that approximate value and runs with it, producing the results you're seeing.

Try:

```
BigDecimal velocity = new BigDecimal(-7, 2);
BigDecimal afterMultiplyingBy200 = velocity.multiply( new BigDecimal(2, -2) );
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_FLOOR), `ROUND_FLOOR` rounds towards negative infinity, thus rounding `-14.000...` to `-15`.

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at [RoundingMode](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/RoundingMode.html), especially `HALF_UP`.